# Как правильно посчитать "бриошь"

Tags: падежи, числительные

Как правильно посчитать "бриошь"? Например, две бриоши? Верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Викисловарь говорит, что [вы правы](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%8C#:%7E:text=%D0%98%D0%BC.%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%CC%81%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%CC%81%D1%88%D0%B8%20%D0%A0.%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%CC%81%D1%88%D0%B8,%2D%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%8C%20%2D.%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%5B%5D).